# Base point of BU/BO, classifying space of U/O.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits

There are principal bundles  $$U(n) \to V_k(\mathbb{C}^n) \to G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$$ and $$O(n) \to V_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to G_k(\mathbb{R}^n),$$ where $V_k(\mathbb{F}^n)$ and $G_k(\mathbb{F}^n)$ are the complex/real ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$)  *Stiefel* and *Grassmannian Manifold* respectively. Customarily the universal bundles and the classifying spaces of $U=\operatorname{colim}_{\to n}U(n)$ or $O=\operatorname{colim}_{\to n}O(n)$ are now formed by passing to the inductive limit/colimit over $n$ and then $k$. Since homotopy classes of pointed maps are important for the classification I wondered what the base point of these spaces is? Based on [the nlab article on the category of pointed objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pointed+object#limits_and_colimits) (there is an error in 2., i.e. it should read "the colimits are the *colimit* in $\mathcal{C}$ of the diagrams with the basepoint adjoined" right?) it is "just" an adjoint point?

Comment: Note: every topological group has a basepoint which is preserved by any continuous homomorphism. Similarly any quotient of a based space has a canonical basepoint. Application: all the spaces in the bundles you write down are pointed, as is each space in the (homotopy) colimits you are forming. Implication: everything in sight has a canonical basepoint.

Comment: @Tyrone I'm not sure if that really addresses the question, as the notation "$F \to E \to B$" typically means just that $F$ is the typical fiber of a fiber bundle, with or without a basepoint of $B$ specified. Regarding the question itself, assuming you take the embedding $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ to be as "the first n coordinates", then a standard basepoint is given by the standard "first k coordinates" k-plane. By the way, that nLab assertion is still not quite correct, e.g. the empty colimit in $C^{*/}$ will not generally be computed in $C$.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee The nLab doesn't claim that the forgetful functor $C^{*/}\to C$ preserves colimits, but that you take the colimit in $C$ *after* "adjoining a basepoint", to I guess the whole diagram. So you take the colimit in $C$ over the diagram indexed by the cone over the original indexing category, which I believe is the correct description. It's certainly vaguely put, though.

Comment: @KevinArlin Sure, that sounds more reasonable. A related fact is that the forgetful functor $C^{\ast/} \to C$ preserves _connected_ colimits.